# RaiseCanExecuteChanged() on a RelayCommand<enum> doesn't cause CanExecute() to be called

Tags: mvvm, enums, uwp, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml

here comes my first question.

In a UWP application with MVVM Light, I'm trying to define **just one** command with an enumerative parameter to respond to all button interactions in the view. However buttons remain disabled and not responsive.

I have defined the parameter for the command

```cs
public enum ButtonKey
{
    Connect = 0,
    Disconnect = 1
}
```

which is then used by the MainViewModel class

```cs
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    RelayCommand<ButtonKey> buttonPressed;
    public RelayCommand<ButtonKey> ButtonPressed
    {
        get => buttonPressed;
        set => buttonPressed = value;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        buttonPressed = new RelayCommand<ButtonKey> (ButtonPressed_Execute, ButtonPressed_CanExecute);
    }

    bool ButtonPressed_CanExecute(ButtonKey arg)
    {
        bool retValue = false;
        switch (arg)
        {
            // The following conditions are just for testing
            case ButtonKey.Connect:
                retValue = true;
                break;
            case ButtonKey.Disconnect:
                retValue = false;
                break;
        }
        return retValue;
    }

    void ButtonPressed_Execute(ButtonKey obj)
    {
        // another switch() case:
    }
}
```

Then the xaml code is the following:

```xml
<CommandBar>
    <AppBarButton Label="Connect" Command="{Binding ButtonPressed}">
        <AppBarButton.CommandParameter>
            <viewModel:ButtonKey>Connect</viewModel:ButtonKey>
        </AppBarButton.CommandParameter>
    </AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton Label="Disconnect" Command="{Binding ButtonPressed}">
        <AppBarButton.CommandParameter>
            <viewModel:ButtonKey>Disconnect</viewModel:ButtonKey>
    </AppBarButton.CommandParameter>
</AppBarButton>
```

The `ButtonPressed_CanExecute(ButtonKey arg)` method is not called even with a `buttonPressed.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` call in the `MainViewModel` constructor.

I think that all is caused by the enumerative type used as the command parameter, but I cannot figure out why. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the source code of MvvmLight and found the issue. In the [`RelayCommand<T>`'s source](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/b23c4d5bf6df654ad885be26ea053fb0efa04973/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Command/RelayCommandGeneric.cs), you will find the following check within the `CanExecute` method:

```cs
if (parameter == null || parameter is T)
{
    return (_canExecute.Execute((T)parameter));
}
```

For some reason, the enum `parameter` of the method is an `int`, not an instance of your enum when the check is being performed. Because of that, the second check will fail.

If you update your code to work with `int`, it will work as expected:

```cs
public RelayCommand<int> ButtonPressed { get; set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    ButtonPressed = new RelayCommand<int>(ButtonPressed_Execute, ButtonPressed_CanExecute);            
}

bool ButtonPressed_CanExecute(int arg)
{
    bool retValue = false;
    switch (arg)
    {
        // The following conditions are just for testing
        case (int) ButtonKey.Connect:
            retValue = true;
            break;
        case (int) ButtonKey.Disconnect:
            retValue = false;
            break;
    }
    return retValue;
}

void ButtonPressed_Execute(int  obj)
{
    // another switch() case:
}
```

I find it quite surprising and I guess this should be addressed as a bug in MvvmLight.

Comment: I agree Martin Zikmund's suggestion. @Oreste Riccardo Natale you could report this issue on [Github](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/issues) and you could use Martin Zikmund's code as a workaround.

Comment: I will try to do a Pull request on MvvmLight repo with a fix today :-)

Comment: Thank you @MartinZikmund, it does work! Given your insight, now I just wonder if this behaviour is indeed as wanted. Should the right approach be to use a ValueConverter from/to int and the enum type?

Comment: Actually I find the fact that enum values appear as `int` quite surprising, but I think the best would be to fix this in MvvmLight so that the framework can handle `int` -> `enum` conversion and you could use the `enum` as generic type parameter of `RelayCommand` and keep the XAML the same as now. The `int` should be rather a temporary solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the command parameter using the x:static markup extension

```
<AppBarButton Label="Connect" 
              Command="{Binding ButtonPressed}"
              CommandParameter="{x:Static viewModel:ButtonKey.Connect}" />
```

Comment: x:Static is not available in UWP